dense subspace of a Hilbert space is the domain of some unbounded operator
The following is a statement from the text Non Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications by Lions and Magenes section 2.1. We aim to show that Given two Hilbert spaces $X\subset Y$ with $X$ dense in $Y$ with continuous injection, $X$ can be identified as the domain of a densely defined unbounded operator on $Y$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two separable Hilbert space with the property
\begin{equation*} X \subset Y,\quad X\text{ dense in }Y\text{ with
continuous injection}. \end{equation*} Let $(\;,\;)_X$ and $(\;,\;)_Y$ be the scalar products in $X$ and $Y$ respectively. We denote by $D(S)$ the set of
$u$'s such that the antilinear form $v\mapsto
 (u,v)_X,\, v\in X$ is continuous in the topology
induced by $Y$. Then $(u,v)_X = (Su,v)_Y$
which defines $S$ as an unbounded operator in $Y$,
with domain $D(S)$.

The authors claimed that it is easy to see that $D(S)$ is dense in $Y$, is there a way to see this?
(P.s. if we take the example of $X=H^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $Y=L^2(\mathbb{R})$, it is easy to see that $S = \Delta$ and $D(S) = H^2(\mathbb{R})$)

Define $\mathfrak{a}\colon X\times X \to \mathbb{C}$ by
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{a}(u,v) = (u,v)_{X} + (u,v)_{Y}.
\end{equation}
It is straightforward to check that $\mathfrak{a}$ is an inner product on $X$. The norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathfrak{a}}$ on $X$ induced by $\mathfrak{a}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\|u\|_{\mathfrak{a}} = (\|u\|_{X}^{2} + \|u\|_{Y}^{2})^{1/2}.
\end{equation}
Since the injection of $(X,\|\cdot\|_{X})$ into $(Y,\|\cdot\|_{Y})$ is continuous, the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathfrak{a}}$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_{X}$. Consequently, $X$ equipped with the inner product $\mathfrak{a}$ is a Hilbert space.
We now show that $I+S$ is surjective. Let $f\in Y$. Define $\phi \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ by
\begin{equation}
\phi (v) = (v,f)_{Y}.
\end{equation}
As $\phi$ is the composition of the continuous injection of $(X, \|\cdot\|_{X})$ into $(Y, \|\cdot\|_{Y})$ and the continuous linear map
\begin{equation}
v\mapsto (v,f)_{Y}
\end{equation}
from $Y$ into $\mathbb{C}$, it follows that $\phi$ is an element of $(X, (\cdot , \cdot )_{X})^{*} = (X, \mathfrak{a})^{*}$. Hence there is some $u\in X$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{a}(v, u) = (v, f)_{Y}
\end{equation}
for all $v\in X$, or equivalently that
\begin{equation}
(u, v)_{X} = (f-u, v)_{Y}
\end{equation}
for all $v\in X$. Then $u\in D(S)$ and $Su = f - u$, so it follows that $(I+S)u = f$.
Now it takes little work to establish that $D(S)$ is dense in $Y$. Let $f\in D(S)^{\perp}$. Since $I+S$ is surjective there is some $u\in D(S)$ such that $(I+S)u = f$. Then
\begin{equation}
0 = (f,u)_{Y} = (u,u)_{Y} + (Su,u)_{Y} = \|u\|_{Y}^{2} + \|u\|_{X}^{2},
\end{equation}
so it follows that $u = 0$ and hence $f = 0$. This completes the proof.
Proposition 1.22 of "Analysis of Heat Equations on Domains" by Ouhabaz has a more general version of this result for those who are interested.
